# Are all Cannondale Slice forks compatible with a Cannondale Slice 105 frame?

Tags: fork, replacement, cannondale

I recently bought a Cannondale Slice 105 (2015) off of Craigslist, and the fork was cut way too short, so I need a new one. I tried going through the local Cannondale dealer, but they couldn't help me, so I'm looking for used ones online.

I'm finding quite a few Slice variants: Premium, Coda, and Ultra, to name a few.
Assuming they are the correct size (1 1/8"), will they automatically fit, or are there any other variables I need to consider?

Comment: @Criggie If you want to make an answer out of this, I'll mark the question as solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doesn't need to be a cannondale fork, just needs to be the right diameter(s) and long enough to get out the top of the frame and be clamped by the stem.

Check wheel mounting tech and brake mounts too, but you can use any fork that fits.